# why packing multiple times?

Tags: java, pack

```
public PenApp() {
    super("PenApp");
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
    pack();
    setResizable(false);
    pack();
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setLocation((d.width - CANVAS_SIZE) / 2, (d.height - CANVAS_SIZE) / 2);
    setSize(CANVAS_SIZE + getInsets().left + getInsets().right,
        CANVAS_SIZE + getInsets().top + getInsets().bottom);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
    });

    img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage
        (getClass().getResource("penguin.gif"));
    img2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage
        (getClass().getResource("kuwa.gif"));
    enableEvents(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
    x = getInsets().left;
    y = getInsets().top;

    setVisible(true);
}
```

a piece of code like this. And I'm just wondering why using several pack() and setVisible() here. 
Thank you :)

Comment: My first thought is 'because the programmer had no idea what they were doing, and just kept cop/pasting lines of code until it magically worked'.  Don't study code like that, and don't base your code on an API that is written like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We place items inside a container and we can set their sizes via setSize or pack. pack is preferrable since it sizes the frame so all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes; pack leaves frame layout manager in charge of the frame size.

Since we are setting some GUI elements as invisible we don't want blank space there so perhaps that's why it's being used again and again. I would run that application by commenting all the packs in between and verify if it's indeed necessary.

Comment: The explanation the author gives is that the behavior of pack() method is limited by the execution environment. And the multiple usage of these two methods is to handle those differences caused by enviornment... Actually I don't understand his words

Comment: @bunnyshell  I suspect that nobody, including the author, understands those words.  What is an URL for this API?

Comment: What he's saying is that he's using the setVisible/pack to minimize/eliminate differences in the way Swing renders components across different windowing systems (mac, windows, unix).  My guess is that the author 'gave up and slapped a lot of code it' to make something work, without really understanding where things went wrong.  That said, I'd be cautious about removing it until you're prepared to address those issues.

Comment: @Richard Being even more careful I'd toss that code out the window and hit the tutorials.

Comment: Yea ... it looks like a classic example of Voodoo coding - http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?VoodooChickenCoding

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's extracted form a book. I've post the whole method

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, since it's from a book, and not "production code", I'd absolutely agree!